# Thumbnail hover popup on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hover, thumbnails

[Graphicriver](http://graphicriver.net/) uses a "Thumbnail hover popup" technique on it's thumbnails.

When you hover on a thumbnail a bigger image is displayed as you can see on my screenshot below:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IO6ua.png]

I believe they are using this:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/thumbnail_hover_popup
Demo:  http://home.comcast.net/~littlemoe85/thumbhover/index.html

How can I achieve this on my wordpress blog?

Any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to know how to use jQuery to achieve this effect. Then follow the plugin's instruction [here](http://codebit.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/jquery-thumbnail-popup-plugin-for-greasemonkey/)

You may also dig into the demo source code to see how the plugin used.

Sorry, no step by step walkthrough because it is so long and depending on your wordpress setup.

Good luck pal.